# Output of php into html not shown

Tags: php, html, mysql, printing, lamp

I am writing a simple php application with mysql integration.
I have a simple html page in which I am connecting with the database and then for   verification, I want to print the host info.

I have [this in the html file.](http://pastebin.com/fD34CW5H)
The output are the two horizontal bars with nothing between them.

What's wrong with the code?

I am writing at ubuntu 12.10, at aptana studio (also using lamp).

Comment: I tried the code; at the very least, you should see 'Host information: ' between the lines.  Are you sure you don't see that?!?!?  If you don't, then please stub out the mysql lines and just set link to some dummy value and at least see what you are getting.  It could be an error propagating from mysql

Comment: whats the extension of your file name. .html or .php? as Ronald said if php is getting interpreted correctly then your should atleast see "Host information" string printed. If the extension is .html for your file then above will not work unless you process .html as .php.  I could be off here but thats just my 2 cents

Comment: @Newbie: That's how I saw it at the presentation.

Comment: @RonaldBarzell: I've changed these: '$link = "WHAT?!";
        printf("Problem: %s\n", $name);' and still nothing.

Comment: @JaspreetChahal: It's .html. What do you mean with "add process .html as .php" ?

Comment: @Chris Are you using a .php extension?

Comment: @RonaldBarzell: The file that contains all the code has a .html extension. :S (Sorry for being a total newbie, first time trying to write html+php+mysql)

Comment: @Chris it needs a .php extension

Comment: @RonaldBarzell: Renamed it to .php and opened the file in chrome, and still nothing.

Comment: @Chris Copy & paste the example in my answer below and save it as test.php then run it.  If it still doesn't work, then maybe your PHP is not configured properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All indications are that your PHP is not being executed period.  Your DB code may still be off, but we're not even at that point yet.  This implies one of two things are going on.  Either your extension is wrong, or your PHP is not configured.

First, try this script (save it as info.php):

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If that doesn't work, then you are not configured. If that does work, then try this slightly longer bare-bones example; it's your code, sans the database connectivity.  You should see a stub message between the lines.  Again, don't forget the .php extension when saving it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Database Management Systems II - 2nd assignment</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hr>
        <?php
            $link = 'link';
            printf("Host information: %s\n", $link);
        ?>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I am completely wrong with the way I am executing it. I created the file test.php (with root privileges) at /var/www/ and ran it and it worked. How can I use aptana studio, or geanny to write to /var/www/ ?

Comment: I've never used those tools; I would imagine there should be an option to change the "publishing" area or some such...

Comment: Which tool do you recommend using for php + html?

Comment: I use jEdit for both, but but I don't do a lot of heavy html.  I'm either generating it via code, doing light-stuff manually, or using third party GUI libraries.

Comment: I would like to use something with gui that when I click run, a tab would open at my browser and it would be loaded correctly. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: It is highly plausible that your php file will not run as root. Your webserver shouldn't be running as root. It should be running as WWW, apache, or the non root user that you should be logged in as. Your apache log file will show the error.

Comment: @Chris most programming editors have hooks you can use to run compilers and what not.  You could just configure the hook to run your .php directly, or if needed a script that sets things up for your php.

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit off on your MySQLi object, it should be more like..

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");
printf("Host Information: %s\n", $link->host_info);
```

MySQLi is an object oriented system, host_info is a public member that you can access once you have a valid instance of MySQLi.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-host-info.php

EDIT:
Allow error reporting and check connection.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Database Management Systems II - 2nd assignment</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hr>
        <?php
            $link = mysqli_connect("host","username","pass","database");
            if(mysqli_connect_error())
                echo "MySQLi Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            else
                echo "MySQLi Host Info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link);
        ?>     
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysqli also supports Procedural style. That makes Chris's code correct. He should atleast see "Host information" printed.

Comment: This is how I saw it at the pdf our instructor gave us. :/

Comment: I wasn't aware that mysqli had procedural api's as well.  All the same you can try echo instead of printf.  echo "Host Information: " .mysqli_get_host_info($link);

Comment: I am trying echo "blaa"; and it doesn't show up. I must be doing sth completely wrong!

Comment: If your php error reporting is turned off or not sensitive to warnings you might have something crashing it's execution.  You should still see the error_log file, try reading that for more information.  Also use error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE); to enabled error reporting on a per script basis.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are actually connecting to your database:

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```